# How do you use client pass parameters to a React Server Component to use in your API calls?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do you use client pass parameters to a React Server Component to use in your API calls? For example, suppose I have the following API endpoint:

`GET /api/search?term=<search term>`

such as this, for example:

```
async function fetchData(searchTerm){
      const data = await fetch(`https://myapi.com/api/search?term=${searchTerm}`);
      return data.json();
}
```

And it then hits a database, and returns an array of results.

Now suppose from a Client Component, I have an input that lets the user enter some text (or click a radio button, or choose something from a dropdown, it doesn't matter)

How can I get the data that the user selected / entered from their interaction in to my Server Component, so that I can then craft the appropriate API call? For example, if they enter "purple" in an input box, how can I have my server component call

`GET /api/search?term=purple`

Or similarly, make a POST request with a body that uses user-provided data?

Is this possible ? Or are Server Components only capable of fetching data from a static URL without any added query strings or body params that are defined by something the user did?

Comment: from your server component, you have a child client component, you will be kinda listening for the user interaction from this child component and based on user interaction, you want to make an API request in the parent server component. is that right?

Comment: @Yilmaz I have a server component that has a client component in it, that then wraps the server component that makes the API call, in accordance with the example in the Next.JS 13 docs https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials